# Is it possible to improve the performance of SQLite writing and compressed uploading through memory operations?

Tags: performance, sqlite

I have a ask.
1.Create sqlite and write large amounts of data.
2.Then compressed and uploaded to the file server.

Now all operations are run in disk files.How to improve performance?
Is it possible to run all steps in memory.

Comment: Yes, no, it depends. What type of answer do you expect?

Comment: 1) Research the SQLite forum instead; start [here](https://sqlite.org/forum/info/f832398c19d30a4a); 2) Yes, on systems which support this (Linux-based systems do) you can have a so-called RAM disk which looks like a filesystem but is contained in memory; 3) Such kind of questions are [off-topic on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic); 4) Your question has nothing to do with Go.